# Entering a variable amount of data into a database with the best normalization possible

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, many-to-many

ok, so I have a database comprising of two tables, products and suppliers.

All suppliers fill in a form and their data is then stored in the suppliers table, and the products table contains a list of all of the products, so when the supplier fills in the form, he can choose as many products as he wishes as I use jQuery JSON and AJAX to get the list of all of the products and then populate a drop down list with all of them in it, which can then be cloned as many times as is needed.

The problem I am sitting with now is, how do I insert all of the different products the supplier chooses into the supplier table, or should I rather just relate all of the products he chooses to the one supplier for better normalization since all the products are already there?

I will be using jQuery $.ajax to POST the form data in JSON format to a waiting PHP file, which will then parse it and insert the data into the database.

So basically, I need to figure out how to relate the data in the database to achieve the best normalization possible, and I need to figure out a way of inserting a variable amount of products into the suppliers table or find a way to relate the many products he chooses to the one supplier.

I am very new to relational databases, so any advice on how to proceed would be a great help, so would any other advice you guys may have!

The jQuery code I use to populate clone and POST the products the supplier chooses:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var count = 0;      

        //when clicked it will remove the closest div with a class of 'container'
        $("span.remove").live('click', function(){
            $(this).closest("div.container").fadeOut(400, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                $('#button').attr('disabled','');
            });
        });

        //initialize the button
        $('#button').attr('disabled','');
        $('#button').click(function(){

            var count = $("#systems_wrapper > .container").size();
            var lastID = $("#systems_wrapper > .container:last").attr('id');
            var exploded = lastID.split("_");
            var increment = Number(exploded[1])+1;

            //if the user has selected 5 products, disable the 'add' button
            if(count >= 5){
                $('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }else {
                $('#button').attr('disabled','');
            }

            //clone the first drop down and give it a different ID, as well as it's child elements
            var test = $('#systems_0.container').clone().attr('id', 'system_' + increment).appendTo('#systems_wrapper');
            test.children(':nth-child(2)').append('<span class="remove"></span>');
            test.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'mail_' + increment).attr('class','dropDowns').attr('onchange','test();');


            });


    //get the products JSON object returned from test_post.php and run the necessary functions on the returned data
    $.getJSON("test_post.php", function(data){

    //clean out the select list
    $('#box').html('');

        //run the loop to populate the drop down list
        $.each(data, function(i, products) {
            $('#box').append(
                $('<option></option>').html(products.products)
            );
        });
    });
});


//this gets all of the products chosen and then gets each ones value and ID, and then posts it to the qwer.php file

function test(){
    var sections = $('#systems_wrapper').find('.dropDowns');
    var newArray = new Array();

    sections.each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();
        var o = { 'id': id, 'value': val };

        newArray.push(o);
    });

    alert(newArray);

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "qwer.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { json: JSON.stringify(newArray) }
        });

}
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: You know, the way you collect and present data on client side is not directly relevant to your question, which is about database design.

Comment: Well, part of the question is about getting the variable amount of products into the database once it gets sent, so it just seemed right to show how I was gathering and sending it to the PHP file. I can see how it might be a little bit excessive, but rather too much than too little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the problem correctly from a database level, should you be using an intermediate table called something like ProductSupplier containing a Product_ID and Supplier_ID column.

Then when a supplier selects a product, add both the supplier and product id to a new column in this table.

This will allow multiple suppliers to pick the same product and multiple products to be picked by the same supplier.

EDIT: I meant to say "add both the supplier and product id to a new ROW in this table"

Comment: Any idea on how to enter each of the products into that table then? Can I use something like a foreach loop?

Comment: I have never used jQuery before, but by the looks of your code, you have an array of products ids (as integers) called newArray which contains all of the selected products.

In c# the syntax would be "foreach (int id in newArray) { /*Code to insert single row*/ }"

Comment: The php for this would be something like "foreach ($newArray as $Product_ID) { /*Write line to db*/ }". Apologies for not being able to help with the jQuery side of it. ( http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php )